# Can we refactor our class if its fully written in .h file into .h + .cpp using Visual Assist X?

Tags: oop, visual-c++, visual-assist

Can we refactor our class if its fully written in .h file into .h + .cpp using  Visual Assist X? (I mean having all functions written in .h file)

Comment: I don't know about VAX, but it would be easy do with Eclipse plug-in (there's a module for rewriting the syntax tree, which would do all the work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VA feature [Move Implementation to Source File](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/moveImplementation.asp) can help you move methods from a class header to the class source file.